# VSCode - Devcontainers - Source Bash Profile

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

Is it possible to source a .bash_profile or equivalent in every terminal window when using DevContainers.

There are numerous options in devcontainers.json, but they seem about importing functions or envars from the Host/User environment.

In my case I'm baking a file into the base image. I want that file sourced when a user opens a new terminal in the container.